# #1062 - Duplicate entry '87' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a big problem with phpmyadmin,

I have two tables where I want to add a status message like Facebook.

My first table I have ID, username and password

and in my second I have id, status message, thumbs up, thumbs down.

Now I want when adding a "status message" I'll send the id of the foreign key from the user.

But I get only error of this kind:

```
 # 1062 - Duplicate entry '87 'for key' PRIMARY '
```

kit that I try to write the

```
 INSERT INTO `notes` (`id`, `note`) VALUES ("87", "hello")
```

Also good to know is that my database is already a post from id = 87 but want to be able to have more.

Answer (score 2):

Try just this, if the id is auto increment, you don't have to make it:

```
INSERT INTO `notes` ( `note`) VALUES ("hello")
```

Comment: new error message : Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`webbutvecklare`.`notes`, CONSTRAINT `notes_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `user` (`m_pk`))